# Autocomplete with ajax call(Json) in laravel, no response

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

**I have the view:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" /> 
<script>

$(function()
{
   $( "#q" ).autocomplete({
    source : "{{ url('search/autocomplete') }}",
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $('#q').val(ui.item.value);
    }
  });
});
</script>

<input id="q" placeholder="Search users" name="q" type="text" value="">
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\NewTheme;
use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Auth;
use Response;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
public function autocomplete(){
    $term = Input::get('term');

    $results = array();

    // this will query the users table matching the TagName

    $queries = DB::table('New_Themes')
        ->where('TagName', 'like', '%'.$term.'%')
        ->take(5)->get();

    foreach ($queries as $query)
    {
        $results[] = ['value' => $query->TagName];
    }
return Response::json($results);
}
}
```

**And my route:**

```
Route::get('search/autocomplete', 'SearchController@autocomplete');
```

My problem is that when I type more then 3 letters in input tag I don't get anything, which seems that input with q id isn't filled with the values. If I do add the form/action/method thing with submit button the controller works fine, so the problem is in this ajax call which doesn't work properly.

Any thoughts why this isn't working properly(maybe it the ajax call doesn't get properly to route or something like this)?

**FINAL SOLUTION thanks to stack and Borna:**

**View:**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="TagName" id="searchname" name="TagName">

<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#searchname').autocomplete({
        source:'{!!URL::route('autocomplete')!!}',
          minlength:1,
          autoFocus:true,
          select:function(e,ui)
          {
              $('#searchname').val(ui.item.value);
          }
      });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\NewTheme; //Instead of NewTheme, your model name
use Input;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;

class Theme extends Controller {  //Instead of Theme your own controller name
    public function autocomplete(Request $request)
{
    $term = $request->term;

    $queries = DB::table('New_Themes') //Your table name
        ->where('TagName', 'like', '%'.$term.'%') //Your selected row
        ->take(6)->get();

    foreach ($queries as $query)
    {
        $results[] = ['id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->TagName]; //you can take custom values as you want
    }
return response()->json($results);
}
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/autocomplete', array('as' => 'autocomplete', 'uses'=>'Theme@autocomplete')); //Instead of Theme your Controller name
```

Comment: I am using 5.2 v, laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "#q" ).autocomplete({
    source : "{!!URL::route('search/autocomplete')!!}",
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $('#q').val(ui.item.value);
    }
```

in controller 
  use `return response()->json($results);`  instead of return Response::json($results);

another code for autocomplete
In view

```
<input type="text" name="searchname" class="form-control" id="searchname" placeholder="search" />

$(document).ready(function () {

      $('#searchname').autocomplete({


          source:'{!!URL::route('autocomplete')!!}',

          // source:"{{ URL::to('autocomplete')}}",
          minlength:1,
          autoFocus:true,
          select:function(e,ui)
          {
              alert(ui);


          }

      });


   });
```

in controller

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
{

      $term=$request->term;
      $data=PaymentInvoice::where('invoice_number','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')->take(10)->get();
      //var_dump($data);

      $results=array();


      foreach ($data as $key => $v) {

          $results[]=['id'=>$v->id,'value'=>$v->invoice_number." Project Name: ".$v->project_name." Amount: ".$v->amount];

      }

      return response()->json($results);

  }
```

In model

```
class PaymentInvoice extends Model
{
    //

    protected $table='payment_invoice';
    protected $fillable=['project_name','invoice_number','date','paid_to','prepared_by','amount','invoice_details_id','created_at'];
}
```

Comment: but why 2x !!, what does it mean?

Comment: it says that Route [search/autocomplete] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Comment: var_dump($term); ..see what u get

Comment: Nothing at all with ajax, its null

Comment: ok i will share with u a code that i did before ...hope it will help you

Comment: Route::get('search', [
    'uses' =>'SearchController@autocomplete',
    'as' => 'search'
    ]) write this .see u called in url here u write 'as' as 'as' => 'searchoff' ...but when it goes to routes.php it doesnot get this 'search'

Comment: other way modify source:"{{ URL::to('searchoff')}}",

Comment: yes...my route Route::get('/autocomplete', $arrayName = array('as' => 'autocomplete', 'uses'=>'InvoiceController@autocomplete'));

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqvP4KD9Jcc i follwed this step by step ...u can see

Comment: hey  u forget to add essential js files

Comment: i added:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: I'l try follow step by step the video

Comment: Please refrain from using profanity, even if you're not directing it at people

Comment: I know the problem is that I used that use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input; which went into conflict probably, at the moment i took it off, it worked as butter

Answer (score 0):

---

### Route

```
Route::post('search/autocomplete', 'messagesController@autocomplete');
```

---

### HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('To', 'To:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            {!! Form::text('To', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'To']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

### script

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
    src = "search/autocomplete";

$( "#To" ).autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
            type: 'POST',
            url: src,
            data: {
                term : request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);

            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
select: function(event, ui) {
  $('#To').val(ui.item.value);
}
 });

    });
  <script>
```

---

### Controller

```
public function autocomplete(){
$term = Input::get('term');

$results = array();

$queries = DB::table('rusers')
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
    ->take(5)->get();

foreach ($queries as $query)
{
    $results[] = [ 'id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->name ];
}
return response()->json($results);
}
```