# Keep the information from being viewed from URL in Autocomplete (jQuery / Laravel)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I'm implementing the code in this post:

[Autocomplete with ajax call(Json) in laravel, no response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097105/autocomplete-with-ajax-calljson-in-laravel-no-response)

It uses an ajax call(json) in laravel. Everything works well. However, the route uses 'get' and the query results can be viewed by using the URL. I view this as a security and privacy issue.

What's the best way to keep the information from being viewed when it's not directly called by the autocomplete?

Comment: But why? Every autocomplete request can be reproduced by `curl`.

Comment: shukshin.ivan Can you elaborate?

Comment: You haven't answered yet. Why? Protect from what kind of requests, simple get?

Comment: When the autocomplete .asp file is accessed directly and without a value it 'dumps' the equivalent of a * search.... I think I just answered my own question. I need to insert a default value to limit the output if the URL is accessed directly.

Comment: Well, sometimes right question is more than a half of an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set minimal length of a parameter with validation. Place it into your controller and limit minimal length in the js code `minLength: 3`.

```
use Validator; // at the top of controller

public function search(Request $request) {
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'q' => 'required|min:3',
    ]);

    if ($v->fails()) {
        return [];
    }

    // now you are sure that q has minimum 3 chars
    // search and output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to recognize whether it's called from the autocomplete js or from a get request.

However, you can use the [throttle middleware](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.html) to prevent scraping of your autocomplete data. Use this middleware like so: `'middleware' => 'throttle:60,1'`. This limits the requests for 60 requests per minute, then disables access for 1 minute. Note that the api middleware group has the `throttle:60,1` enabled by default in Laravel 5.2